# What kind of chili plant is this?

Tags: identification, peppers, chili

What kind of chili plant is this? I bought this chili plant from the market today but don't know what kind of chili it is. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: a quick internet search showed this: https://www.chileplants.com/search.aspx?SearchName=MINI+YELLOW+BELL+PEPPER+PLANTS&ProductCode=PEPMYB&SizeID=&SearchMode=simple&LengthID=&WidthID=4&HeightID=2,3&OrientationID=&FoliageID=&FleshID=&UseID=&Color=yellow&Location=&Keyword=&HeatID=&TypeID=&DeterminancyID=&CategoryID=1&SeasonID=&NewProduct=&Letter=&SearchButton=Pressed&pagesize=20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The erect habit of fruit setting is a unique characteristic of ornamental peppers and wild pepper species. The erect habit is known to be controlled by the up locus on pepper (Capsicum annuum L.) chromosome 12 [source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18824887)

They're normally bred for the colour and appearance but can be eaten

> Ornamental peppers are safe to eat, but they are normally grown for their attractive color and ornamental qualities rather than their flavor, which you may find disappointing. Most people consider them too hot to enjoy anyway. Peppers bred for culinary use produce better fruit for eating. [source](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/pepper/grow-ornamental-pepper-plants.htm)

It might be a hungarian wax pepper